# Align text vertically next to image

Tags: html, css

How do I align my block of text vertically centrered with my image so my text appears in the middle, yet to the side?

My [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/da08ayLd/).

```
<div class="avatar">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <div>
        <span>MyAvatar.jpg</span>
        Avatars should be no bigger than 200x200px
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Your `div` has to be the same height as the image, 50px. Then give the `div` a `line-height` of 50px.

Comment: @WQuaniran: no, he has in div two lines, it works with a single line only (`span` has `display: block` to be in the single line).

Comment: You can try to make two spans. Give them both a absolute position?

Comment: @WQuaniran: why, when he can works perfectly with this html code?

Comment: @panther, better more than nothing right?

Comment: @WQuaniran: don´t know if it´s better to put there X bad "solutions"  when underneath is perfect solution with current html markup and independent of number of lines and their height. What you will do with a two-line avatar name using absolute positioning? It seems avatars will be different, he used 50x50 and wrote about size <200x200... Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: table` and `vertical-align`.

```
.avatar {
    display: table;
}

.avatar div {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/da08ayLd/1/

Comment: @panther - good one and fast one lol ,liked your answer but don't think that i copied yours :S

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
body {font-size:12px}

.avatar {
    display:table;

}
.avatar div
{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle
    }

.avatar span {
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.avatar img {

    margin-right:20px;
    display:table-cell;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/da08ayLd/2/